# Jquery Mobile transition event not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, css-transitions

I'm making use if Jquery mobile for its data-transition="slide".
Thats working fine, each page loaded is its own page,not tab data sliders (if that makes any difference)

I'm trying to have some JavaScript trigger after the page has been loaded by the slider transition.
I have a js file that is to set the max height of a control - this works fine if I'm on the page and refresh but if its loaded by the sliding transition, the JavaScript wont fire. I've tried it in pageinit, pageload etc but nothing triggers.

Can anyone point out the issue here. 
App.JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var header = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
var footer = document.getElementById('pagefooter').offsetHeight;
var wrapperH = window.innerHeight - header - footer - 50;
document.getElementById('maincontent').style.height = wrapperH + 'px';
});

$(document).on("pageinit", function (event) {
    var header = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
    var footer = document.getElementById('pagefooter').offsetHeight;
    var wrapperH = window.innerHeight - header - footer - 50;
    document.getElementById('maincontent').style.height = wrapperH + 'px';
});

$(document).off('pageshow');
$(document).on('pageshow', function (e, ui) {
    // generally written in pagechange event.
    var header = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
    var footer = document.getElementById('pagefooter').offsetHeight;
    var wrapperH = window.innerHeight - header - footer - 50;
    document.getElementById('maincontent').style.height = wrapperH + 'px';
});
```

Base mvc layout page

```
@{
    ViewData["Logo"] = "bird.png";
    ViewData["Icon"] = "cascade.ico";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="Robots" content="noindex" />
    <title>@ViewBag.SiteTitle</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/img/@ViewBag.Icon" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

    <environment names="Development">
        <!-- Dev uses full file versions for de-bugging -->
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-mobile-min/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-mobile-min/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </environment>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="~/styles/all/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/Mobile/mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 481px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/Desktop/desktop.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 481px)" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div id = "header" data-role="header" data-id="persistent" data-position="fixed">
            <div id="headnav" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-toggle navbar-text" data-toggle="collapse">
                        <h3 class="title">@ViewBag.Title</h3>
                        <h5 class="subtitle">@ViewBag.SubTitle</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-left" rel="home" href="#" title="@ViewBag.SiteTitle">
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "App")" title="Home">
                            <img style="max-width:100px; max-height: 100px; margin-top: 5px"
                                 src="~/img/@ViewBag.Logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-text">
                        <h3 class="title">@ViewBag.Title</h3>
                        <h5 class="subtitle">@ViewBag.SubTitle</h5>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Logout Box -->
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        @await Component.InvokeAsync("Logout")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- content -->
        <div id="maincontent" data-role="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

        <footer id="pagefooter" data-id="persistent" data-position="fixed">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="footer-body">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("MyDetails", "App")"><img src="~/img/icons/myrecord.png" />My Record</a></li>
                            <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("MyTeam", "App")"><img src="~/img/icons/myteam.png" />Team Headcount</a></li>
                            <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("Holidays", "App")"><img src="~/img/icons/holidays.png" />My Holidays</a></li>
                            <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("Payslips", "App")"> <img src="~/img/icons/payslips.png" />Payslip</a></li>
                            <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("Tasks", "App")"><img src="~/img/icons/tasks.png" />Tasks</a></li>
                            <li><a data-transition="slide" href="@Url.Action("Requests", "App")"><img src="~/img/icons/authorise.png" />Requests</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    @*<div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#footer-body">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="footer-bar-btns visible-xs">
                            <li><a href="#" class="btn" title="History"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-clock-o blue-text">Link 1</i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="btn" title="Favourites"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-star yellow-text">Link 2</i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="btn" title="Subscriptions"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-rss-square orange-text">Link 3</i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <!-- overriding customer styles -->
    <link href="~/styles/customstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just need a way to tigger some JS once the new page has loaded. Does nobody have anything

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort this with CSS in the end.

Knowing the height of the top and bottom menu bars means I could just set the below:

```
#maincontent {
    position: fixed;
    top: 120px;
    bottom: 70px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Now there is no overlap and I can freely debug my site in a browser and it looks correct on any setting.